# Should I set max limits on as many entities as possible in my webapp?

Tags: database, performance

I am working on a CRUD webapp where users create and manager their data assets.
Having no desire to be bombarded with tons of data for the first time, I think that it would be reasonable to set limits where possible in the database.

For example, limit number of created items `A = 10`, `B = 20`, `C = 50` then, if user reaches the limit, have a look at his account and figure out if I should update the rules if it doesn't break the code and performance.

Is it a good practice at all to set such limits from the performance/maintenance side, not from the business side or should I think like data entities are unlimited and try to make it well-performing with lots of data from the start?

Answer (score 1):

You suggest to test your application's performance on real users, which is bad. In addition, your solution will create inconvenience for users by limiting them, when there is no reason for that (at least from user's point of view), which decreases user's satisfaction.

Instead, you should test performance before you release. It will give you understanding of your application's and infrastructure's limits of running under high load. Also, it will help you to find and eliminate bottle necks in your code. You can perform such testing with tools like [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org) and many others.

Also, if you afraid of tons of data at start moment, you can release your application as private beta: just make a simple form where users can ask for early access and receive invite. By sending invites you can easily control growth of user base and therefore loading on you app.

But you should, of course, create limitations where it is necessary, for example, limit items per page, etc.